# Console outputing wrong single quote character (â)

Tags: locale

My console `yakuake` is outputting the wrong single quote character.

```
test.cpp: In function âint main()â:
```

I've tried, one by one:

```
export LC_CTYPE="C"    
export LC_CTYPE="posix"
export LC_ALL="en_CA.UTF-8"
export LC_COLLATE=C
export LC_MESSAGES=C
```

but that didn't work, it still outputting that character instead of a single quote.

my current `locale` output:

```
LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

my font was "Anka Coder Condensed".

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does `yakuake` have a character encoding option?  It looks like it's set to ISO 8859-1, but you need to set it to UTF-8.

Comment: It's also interesting that you mention your font, but don't say you tried any other font.  I don't think it's a font issue, but please try another font if you think that's the problem, and report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your character encoding is wrong.  I was able to reproduce your problem by setting it to Western European > ISO 8859-1, but any other Western European encoding likely causes the same symptoms.

Try right clicking inside your `yakuake` window, choosing Set Encoding > Unicode > UTF-8.